# HOW can I implement a logic hooks with sugarcrm?

Tags: php, hook, sugarcrm

I want to implement a Sugar Logic Hook that fires when invoice status becomes validated.

This my logic hook:

```
<?php
    $hook_version = 1; 
    $hook_array = Array(); 
    $hook_array['after_save'] = Array(); 
    $hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(1, 'status invoices Changes', '/var/www/html/suitecrm/modules/AOS_Invoices/AOS_LogicHooks.php','AOS_LogicHooks', 'statusInvoicesChanges'); 
?>`
```

This is my action class:

```
<?php
    class AOS_LogicHooks {

        public function statusInvoicesChanges (SugarBean $bean, $event, $arguments) {
            if ($dictionary['AOS_Invoices']['fields']['status']='validated') { 
                $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Status has been changed");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need a double `==` or triple `===` (strict) to make a comparison. Using one `=` is an assignment operator.

```
if ($dictionary['AOS_Invoices']['fields']['status'] == 'validated') {
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change the path in your logic hooks : `'custom/modules/AOS_Invoices/AOS_LogicHooks.php'` 
And change your code of your action class to:

```
<?php 
class statusChange { 
  public function statusInvoicesChanges ($bean, $event, $arguments) { 
// addition line:
$GLOBALS['log']-> debug(get_class()." ". __FUNCTION__." Status:\n ".print_r($bean->status,true));
    if ($bean->status == 'Validated'){ 
      $GLOBALS['log']-> debug("Status has been changed"); 
    }
  } 
} 
?>
```